# Replace space with hyphen in links

Tags: php, laravel

I need like this
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abc.abcc%26reffer=M1%26name=ABC-DEF-GHI  but now it's Coming https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abc.abcc%26reffer=M1%26name=ABC
DEF  GHI

My Code As Follows

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abc.abcc%26reffer=M{{$data['shopID']}}%26name={{$datastr_replace['-','name']}}
```

Comment: Any reason `str_replace` won't work for you?

Comment: Tim Lewis can you put an example

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php; lots of functional examples in there.

Comment: Tim Lewis, I tired that one but showing error

Comment: Update your question! Show your new code and the error.

Comment: Tim Lewis  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abc.abcc%26reffer=M{{$data['shopID']}}%26name={{$datastr_replace['-','name']}}

Comment: What happened here? `{{$datastr_replace['-','name']}}` That's a syntax error...

Comment: Tim Lewis updated

Comment: Tim Lewis, I don't know how to put that could you help me am new into programming

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to change as like `str_replace(' ', '-', $data['name'])` , may be you have mistaken like `name={{$datastr_replace['-','name']}}`

Answer (score 2):

Given the following array:

```
$data = [
  'shop_id' => 'M',
  'name' => 'ABC DEF GHI'
];
```

You can use the `str_replace()` method to replace all of your `' '` with `-`:

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abc.abcc%26reffer=M{{ $data['shopID'] }}%26name={{ str_replace(' ', '-', $data['name']) }}">Link</a>
```